# How to create and add data to a table where same columns are adjacent?

Tags: html, angular

I've to create a table where two identical columns are adjacent and data should be filled in horizontal pattern based on other field value.

Say, there's a number field and a Add button. On click of add, first data should enter in left column of the table and on adding number again, it should be shown in right column and then again left and this should repeat.

```
NumberCol| NumberCol|
    1    |    2     |
    3    |    4     | ...
```

Something like this.

I'm new to angular and could not get good idea to proceed . I tried something with for loop and if condition, but that did not work.

Field where number will be entered

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Claim Number" #claimNum>
  </mat-form-field>
  <button (click)="onAddClaimNumber(claimNum.value)">Add</button>
```

Table display

```
     <table>
           <thead>
           <tr >
             <th>Claim Number </th>
             <th>Claim Number</th>
           </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
             <div *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
              <tr *ngIf = "i % 2 == 0"  >
                <td>{{field}}
                  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="field.claimNumber" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{field.claimNumber}}" />
                </td>

              </tr>
              </div>
              <div class="secCol" *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index">
                  <tr *ngIf = "i % 2 != 0"  >
                    <td>{{field}}
                      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="field.claimNumber" class="form-control" type="text" name="{{field.claimNumber}}" />
                    </td>

                  </tr>
                  </div>
           </tbody>
         </table>
```

From TS file

```
 private fieldArray: Array<any> = [];
  private newAttribute: any = {};

 public onAddClaimNumber(input : string){
    this.claimNumber = input ;
    this.fieldArray.push(this.claimNumber);
    console.log(this.fieldArray[0])

  }
```

I came across ng-repeat and ng-switch on. But I'm not clear how to use it in my case. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to edit the logic inside your HTML template, i tried to simulate the data of **fieldArray**

Check this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9jjf4z) i created on stackBlitz

Comment: Thanks, but how I can align the value of second column with the first ? In the example you gave, I want 1 and 2 to be at the same level. I tried some CSS, but that doesnt seem to work.